# SOAP client request with transport / Windows account authentication returns Failed to find Authorization header error

Tags: c#, soap

I have to request a SOAP service with transport and Windows account authentication mode.
Whatever the method I use, I always get the same error in response : "Failed to find Authorization header".
I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2015, and .NET Framework 4.6.1.

For creating client and sending request, I use :

```
var client = new MyServiceClient();
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
client.MyRequest();
```

I tried :

1. To use automatically generated service reference with default parameters in app.config.

   ```
   <system.serviceModel>
   <bindings>
     <basicHttpBinding>
       <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService">
         <security mode="Transport" />
       </binding>
     </basicHttpBinding>
   </bindings>
   <client>
     <endpoint address="https://xxxxxxxx:xxxxx/" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService" contract="Service.IMyService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService" />
   </client>
   </system.serviceModel>
   ```
2. To modify `<security mode="Transport" />` by

   ```
   <security mode="Transport">
     <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
   </security>
   ```
3. To remove system.serviceModel section in app.config and to use configuration by code

   ```
   var binding = new BasicHttpBinding
   {
       Security =
       {
           Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport,
           Transport = {ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows}
       }
   };
   var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("https://xxxxxxxx:xxxxx/"));
   this.client = new FrontServiceCvaClient(binding, endpoint);
   ```
4. Only for test purpose, I also set manually login/password

   ```
   this.client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
   ```

Last thing : I get trace log, and actually, I don't see any authentication mention in header

```
System.Net Information: 0 : [22264] ConnectStream#56930466 - Sending headers
{
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://xxxxxxxxxx/IMyService/MyRequest"
Host: xxxxxxxx:xxxxx
Content-Length: 94938294
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
}.
```

For all these cases, I always have same error.
I can't understand why credentials seems no to be added to sent request.
Thanks in advance for any help or advice to understand this behavior.